# Installed second Google Analytics tracking code, pageviews increased and bounce rate dropped exponentially. Any ideas why?

Tags: google-analytics

I installed a second Google Analytics tracking code and have seen my pageviews shoot up, while my bounce rate dropped to almost 0%. Now, I know this isn't correct, even though I wish it were. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-*******-9', 'mydomain');
ga('send', 'pageview');

ga('create', 'UA-*******-1', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker'});
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two send pageview calls to the same tracker (one after you created the first tracker, the second after you created the second tracker, then a third pageview to the second tracker). Remove one of the pageviews to the unnamed tracker.

Comment: And bounce rate dropped because all of those double pageview sends are recorded as subsequent interactions, and therefore not bounces.